# Send Email from Angular Application with attachment

Tags: angular, typescript, email

I'm using Angular9 for developing applications. I want to know how to send email from angular9 application
with csv file attached to it.
Please share some sample code

Comment: You can't send emails from front end.

Comment: You end your csv to backend do your process there not in frontend

Comment: Thanks for the reponse!!! I currently followed this link https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/10/17/create-a-microsoft-outlook-email-using-javascript/  with which it download an eml file that opens in the outlook that will help me to send the mail

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your server to send emails. If you have a back in Node, use nodemailer or something similar.

You can also use third party services like mailjet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse!!! I currently followed this link blogs.perficient.com/2016/10/17/… with which it download an eml file that opens in the outlook that will help me to send the mail

Comment: I see, that's not really a great way to do it. If your app is sending emails, your users shouldn't have to take this step outside your app.